# locking and operation taking long time

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, locking

I think it's a common problem. For example, I have an array which is modified by one process/thread:

```
lock();
for(int i; i<array_size; i++) {
    // find an item and do some operations
}
unlock();
```

There is another process/thread which will print the whole array occasionally, but it may take a "long" time:

```
lock()
for(int i; i<array_size; i++) {
    print(array[i]);
}
unlock();
```

Are there any better approaches to print the whole array?

Answer (score 3):

If it's the printing part that's taking a long time, you could take the lock, take a copy of the array, release the lock and print the array copy.

Comment: This is certainly feasible for small arrays of fast-to-copy types, but if that's similar in running time to printing...

Answer (score 1):

What kind of locks do you use, mutex?    Also what kind of consistency do you expect between the individual cells in your array, when (1) up update them, and (2) when you print them?   If each array-cell is independent, then why not just have many more locks each only responsible for that cells?

Like;

```
mutex locks[array_size];
for (int i=0; i< mutex_size; i++) {
   locks[i].lock();
    // do something or print content...
   locks[i].unlock();   
}
```

However if semantics of your array is such that the cells are not independent of each other but that you need atomic consistency across the array, then you are stuck with your original global lock.

However you could still take a copy of the array under lock and then print the copy, as that would keep the lock of the array at a shorter time not having to wait for the print.

Comment: If consistency between the array elements is not important, one could even use `std::atomic` array types.